# Functional inequalities involving cubing and incrementing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions

Consider the set $S$ of positive increasing invertible functions $f$ satisfying:

$$f((x+1)^3-1)≤(f(x)+1)^3-1$$
$$f(x^3)≥(f(x))^³$$
$$f(x)+1≤f(x+1)$$
for all positive real $x$.

Clearly the identity function is in $S$, since then each inequality holds with equality.

My **question** is: Show that the set $S$ is infinite.
In other words, show that there exist infinitely many functions $f$ for which the above inequalities holds true.

Comment: If $f$ is increasing so is $f^{-1}$. Your third requirement is $f(p_n)+1\le f(p_n)+1$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: Ok corrected.

Comment: You define $f^{-1}$ but do not use it?  Since $f$ is not applied to any value below $\min(p_1,p_1^3)$, you have lots of flexibility in $f$'s definition below this point, easily providing an infinite number of functions.

Comment: The function is only limited on the points corresponding to some specific algebraic combinations of the sequence numbers. On any other input value, we only want $f$ to be increasing. This give you quite some room to work with,  to come up with other functions.

Comment: @Arthur, matt: It can be possible to consider the conditions holds true for for all positive real $x$.

Comment: @Matt: Can you elaborate with the last comment.

Comment: $f(x) = nx$, for $n>1$ ?

Comment: @TheOscillator: This form does not meet the conditions.

Comment: Ok, with your new and different problem, involving $x$, the whole part about $p_n$ is obsolete.  I like your new problem better.  You are looking for a function that is better to apply (if bigger results are better) _after_ cubing, and _after_ incrementing, but _before_ doing $x^3+3x^2+3x$.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, this is the problem.

Comment: @DER: Ok, I edited the problem statement accordingly.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think $S$ contains any function besides the identity?  It doesn't seem easy to find such a function.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, it seems very hard to analyse this problem.